# How to update mysql using an edit button that would send the current data into forms from the simple CMS i made

Tags: php, mysql, database, forms, edit

I am trying to update the values in my database using an edit button. However, I cant figure out how to do it. I cant figure out how to do it,

My goal is that When i press the Edit button of the selected product in inventory.php, it would redirect to the forms i created in update_inv.php, of course filled with the current values that is from the database, and then i can just edit the forms or upload a picture then just click save.

there is and id for each product, but i still cant figure out how to use those to edit the selected product.

for example the product "Apple" is prod_id = 1, i need to edit the all the values with prod_id = 1 in the database using the forms i created.

I hope i explained my situation well enough for you experts to understand my concern. Thank you so much for your help and time understanding my problem.

here is Inventory.php

```
<?php
session_start();
    $conn = @mysql_connect("localhost","root","12148qx3er");
    $db = @mysql_select_db("buybranded");

$qry = "SELECT * FROM inventory";
mysql_set_charset("UTF8");
$result = @mysql_query($qry);
if($result === FALSE) {
    die(mysql_error()); // TODO: better error handling
}
echo "<center>";
echo "<table style='width:800px'>
<tr>

<th>Product ID</th>
<th>Product Brand</th>
<th>Product Category</th>
<th>Product Name</th>
<th>Quantity</th>
<th>Action</th>
<tr>"
;while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){

echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>".$row['prod_id'];
echo "<td>".$row['prod_brand'];
echo "<td>".$row['prod_category'];
echo "<td>".$row['prod_name'];
echo "<td>".$row['prod_quantity'];
echo "<td> <form method='post' action='update_inv.php'><button type='submit'>Edit</button>"; //PROVIDE LINKS FOR QUICK AND FULL EDIT
echo "</tr>";
    }
echo "</table>";
?>
```

Here is the update.php

```
<div id="page-wrap">
  <h1>Edit a Product</h1>
    <form action="updating_inv.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">

      <label for="prod_brand">Product Brand:</label><br />
      <input name="prod_brand" id="prod_brand" type="text" maxlength="150" class="col1" placeholder="Auto Complete Form" required/>
      <div class="clear"></div>

      <label for="prod_name">Product name:</label><br />
      <input name="prod_name" id="prod_name" type="text" maxlength="150" class="col1" required/>
      <div class="clear"></div>

      <label for="prod_category">Category:</label><br />
      <select name="prod_category" class="col1">
      <option <?php if (isset($prod_category) && $prod_category=="  ") ?>>Select Category</option>
      <option <?php if (isset($prod_category) && $prod_category=="Compression") ?>>Compression</option>
      <option <?php if (isset($prod_category) && $prod_category=="Headwear") ?>>Headwear</option>
      <option <?php if (isset($prod_category) && $prod_category=="Shorts") ?>>Shorts</option>
      <option <?php if (isset($prod_category) && $prod_category=="Yoga") ?>>Yoga</option>
      <option <?php if (isset($prod_category) && $prod_category=="Swimming") ?>>Swimming</option>
      <option <?php if (isset($prod_category) && $prod_category=="Fitness Training") ?>>Fitness Training</option>
      <option <?php if (isset($prod_category) && $prod_category=="Water Bottles") ?>>Water Bottles</option>
      <option <?php if (isset($prod_category) && $prod_category=="Sports Socks") ?>>Sports Socks</option>
      <option <?php if (isset($prod_category) && $prod_category=="Sports Bags") ?>>Sports Bags</option>
      <option <?php if (isset($prod_category) && $prod_category=="Protein Shaker") ?>>Protein Shaker</option>
      <option <?php if (isset($prod_category) && $prod_category=="Gloves") ?>>Gloves</option>
      <option <?php if (isset($prod_category) && $prod_category=="Splash Guards") ?>>Splash Guards</option>
      <option <?php if (isset($prod_category) && $prod_category=="Massagers") ?>>Massagers</option>
      <option <?php if (isset($prod_category) && $prod_category=="Sun Blocks") ?>>Sun Blocks</option>
      <option <?php if (isset($prod_category) && $prod_category=="Sports Cleaners") ?>>Sports Cleaners</option>
      </select>
      <div class="clear"></div><br>

      <label for="prod_price">Price:</label><br />
      <input name="prod_price" id="prod_price" type="text" maxlength="10" class="col1" required placeholder="ex. 330"/>
      <div class="clear"></div>

      <label for="prod_desc">Description: (HTML Codes are allowed)</label><br />
      <textarea name="prod_desc" id="prod_desc" class="col2" required></textarea>
      <div class="clear"></div>

      <label for="prod_pic">Upload Image:</label><br />
      <input type="file" name="prod_pic" class="col2" required/>
      <div class="clear"></div><br>

      <label for="prod_quantity">Quantity: (Editable in the Invetory Page)</label><br />
      <input name="prod_quantity" id="prod_quantity" type="text" maxlength="10" class="col2" required placeholder="ex. 10"/>
      <div class="clear"></div>
      <input type="submit" value="Update This Entry!" />
    </form>
    </div>
```

updating_inv.php

```
<?php
session_start();
$con=@mysql_connect("localhost","root","12148qx3er");
$dbcheck = mysql_select_db("buybranded");

    if (!$dbcheck) {
        echo mysql_error();
    }


$image = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['prod_pic']['tmp_name']));
$sql="UPDATE INTO `inventory` (`prod_brand`,`prod_name`,`prod_category`,`prod_price`,`prod_desc`,`prod_quantity`,`prod_pic`)
VALUES 
('$_POST[prod_brand]','$_POST[prod_name]','$_POST[prod_category]','$_POST[prod_price]','$_POST[prod_desc]','$_POST[prod_quantity]','{$image}')";




if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysql_error($con));
  }

header('refresh: 0');
$message = "Product Successfully Updated";
echo("<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$message');</script>");
?>
```

If ever needed, here are the codes for my CMS.php

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
        <title>Add a Product</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="cms.css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.autocomplete.js"></script>
    <script>
     $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#prod_brand").autocomplete("prod_brand_auto_complete.php", {
            selectFirst: true
      });
     });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="page-wrap">
  <h1>Add a Product</h1>
    <form action="add_prod.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">

      <label for="prod_brand">Product Brand:</label><br />
      <input name="prod_brand" id="prod_brand" type="text" maxlength="150" class="col1" placeholder="Auto Complete Form" required/>
      <div class="clear"></div>

      <label for="prod_name">Product name:</label><br />
      <input name="prod_name" id="prod_name" type="text" maxlength="150" class="col1" required/>
      <div class="clear"></div>

      <label for="prod_category">Category:</label><br />
      <select name="prod_category" class="col1">
      <option <?php if (isset($prod_category) && $prod_category=="  ") ?>>Select Category</option>
      <option <?php if (isset($prod_category) && $prod_category=="Compression") ?>>Compression</option>
      <option <?php if (isset($prod_category) && $prod_category=="Headwear") ?>>Headwear</option>
      <option <?php if (isset($prod_category) && $prod_category=="Shorts") ?>>Shorts</option>
      <option <?php if (isset($prod_category) && $prod_category=="Yoga") ?>>Yoga</option>
      <option <?php if (isset($prod_category) && $prod_category=="Swimming") ?>>Swimming</option>
      <option <?php if (isset($prod_category) && $prod_category=="Fitness Training") ?>>Fitness Training</option>
      <option <?php if (isset($prod_category) && $prod_category=="Water Bottles") ?>>Water Bottles</option>
      <option <?php if (isset($prod_category) && $prod_category=="Sports Socks") ?>>Sports Socks</option>
      <option <?php if (isset($prod_category) && $prod_category=="Sports Bags") ?>>Sports Bags</option>
      <option <?php if (isset($prod_category) && $prod_category=="Protein Shaker") ?>>Protein Shaker</option>
      <option <?php if (isset($prod_category) && $prod_category=="Gloves") ?>>Gloves</option>
      <option <?php if (isset($prod_category) && $prod_category=="Splash Guards") ?>>Splash Guards</option>
      <option <?php if (isset($prod_category) && $prod_category=="Massagers") ?>>Massagers</option>
      <option <?php if (isset($prod_category) && $prod_category=="Sun Blocks") ?>>Sun Blocks</option>
      <option <?php if (isset($prod_category) && $prod_category=="Sports Cleaners") ?>>Sports Cleaners</option>
      </select>
      <div class="clear"></div><br>

      <label for="prod_price">Price:</label><br />
      <input name="prod_price" id="prod_price" type="text" maxlength="10" class="col1" required placeholder="ex. 330"/>
      <div class="clear"></div>

      <label for="prod_desc">Description: (HTML Codes are allowed)</label><br />
      <textarea name="prod_desc" id="prod_desc" class="col2" required></textarea>
      <div class="clear"></div>

      <label for="prod_pic">Upload Image:</label><br />
      <input type="file" name="prod_pic" class="col2" required/>
      <div class="clear"></div><br>

      <label for="prod_quantity">Quantity: (Editable in the Invetory Page)</label><br />
      <input name="prod_quantity" id="prod_quantity" type="text" maxlength="10" class="col2" required placeholder="ex. 10"/>
      <div class="clear"></div>
      <input type="submit" value="Create This Entry!" />
    </form>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

and this is the add_prod.php

```
<?php
session_start();
$con=@mysql_connect("localhost","root","12148qx3er");
$dbcheck = mysql_select_db("buybranded");

    if (!$dbcheck) {
        echo mysql_error();
    }


$image = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['prod_pic']['tmp_name']));
$sql="INSERT INTO `inventory` (`prod_brand`,`prod_name`,`prod_category`,`prod_price`,`prod_desc`,`prod_quantity`,`prod_pic`)
VALUES 
('$_POST[prod_brand]','$_POST[prod_name]','$_POST[prod_category]','$_POST[prod_price]','$_POST[prod_desc]','$_POST[prod_quantity]','{$image}')";




if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysql_error($con));
  }

header('refresh: 0; url=cms.php');
$message = "Product Successfully Added";
echo("<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$message');</script>");
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change line 31 in Inventory.php to:

```
echo "<td> <form method='post' action='update_inv.php?id=".$row['prod_id']."'><button type='submit'>Edit</button>";
```

Add to Update.php:

```
<?php
    session_start();
        $itemid = $_GET['id'];
        $conn = @mysql_connect("localhost","root","password");
        $db = @mysql_select_db("buybranded");

    $qry = "SELECT * FROM inventory WHERE prod_id=$itemid";
    mysql_set_charset("UTF8");
    $result = @mysql_query($qry);
    if($result === FALSE) {
        die(mysql_error()); // TODO: better error handling
    }?>
```

Change the forms action from 'action="updating_inv.php"' to 'action="updating_inv.php?id=$itemid"' in update.php

Then set all of your inputs values to be set as the data you received from the query:

```
value="<?php echo mysql_result($result, 0, 'prod_brand');?>"
```

Change updating_inv.php to:

```
$itemid = $_GET['id'];

$sql="UPDATE INTO `inventory` (`prod_brand`,`prod_name`,`prod_category`,`prod_price`,`prod_desc`,`prod_quantity`,`prod_pic`)
VALUES 
('$_POST[prod_brand]','$_POST[prod_name]','$_POST[prod_category]','$_POST[prod_price]','$_POST[prod_desc]','$_POST[prod_quantity]','{$image}') WHERE prod_id=$itemid";
```

There are much better ways to do this I'm sure, but that is what I know. Also you should update all of your mysql queries to mysqli as in PHP5+ it is no longer supported.

Comment: Thank you for your reply and effort, i made those changes however, i got this error in update_inv.php that says unidentified index for prod_id, i used the $itemid=($_GET['prod_id']);

Comment: I updated my codes and weird thing is that the page update_inv.php shows with "Edit a Product" but nothing else shows.

Comment: I fixed it!! THank you @RugerSR9 Thank you for your help and semi-not spoon feeding me. hehe :D

Comment: Oh I had a problem, @RugerSR9,<form method='post' action='update_inv.php?id=".$row['prod_id']."'> only shows id# 1 even when i click on other products, the id is always 1. how do i fix it?

Comment: In your mysql table are the prod_ids all set to 1? If the table of all of the products is appearing correctly it should be working right. Is the id in the url alway set as 1 as well?

Comment: No, they have their own IDs. I havent set them as 1. i think that the loop is not working properly. @RugerSR9

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a hidden input in your html for the ID of the product. If the ID is set then you need to update the row that the ID belongs to. If the ID is not set then you would insert the product as a new row.

You dont really need to have separate code for insert and update. Just the check I explained above.

So at the end of you add_prod file you would have:

```
if (!!$_POST['prod_id']) {
    //Run the update query
}
else {
    //Run the insert query
}
```